# Change ImageButton's image

Tags: android, image, imagebutton, android-drawable

I want to allow the App's user to select from `Drawable` folder an image and change the `ImageButton`'s image.
In my App I put in `Drawable` folder some pictures.

It's possible?

My idea is :
1) There is an `ImageButton`
2) User clic on `setOnLongClickListener`
3) Choose the image from `Drawable` folder and customize icon.

Thanks for all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please post some code, anyway this is a trivial solution:

```
//Execute on onItemLongClick
public void setSelectedDrawable(String imageResName, int selectedDrawableId) {

    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    Drawable drawable = resources.getDrawable(selectedDrawableId);
    if(drawable == null) resources.getIdentifier(imageResName, "drawable", "<package name>");           
    mImageButton.setImageDrawable(drawable);
}
```